# Problema con método en Ruby

Tags: ruby, script

Estoy escribiendo un *script* en el que necesito tratar archivos antiguos. Para eso he creado un método que sirve para fechar los ficheros que le paso. Estos están en diferentes directorios y se extraen de un archivo llamado 'lista', cuyo contenido es:

> home/usuario/prueba/archivo1
>
> /home/usuario/prueba/archivo2
>
> /home/usuario/prueba/carpeta2/archivo3
>
> /home/usuario/prueba/carpeta1/archivo4

El código es:

```
def fechar(nombre)
  (Time.now - File.ctime(nombre))/(24*60*60)
end

File.readlines('lista').each do |linea|
  Dir.chdir(File.dirname(linea))
  puts fechar(File.basename(linea))
end
```

Al ejecutar ese código da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from script.rb:43:in `<main>'
    3: from script.rb:43:in `each'
    2: from script.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
    1: from script.rb:25:in `fechar'
script.rb:25:in `ctime': No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_ctime - archivo1 (Errno::ENOENT)
```

En cambio, si en lugar de `puts fechar(File.basename(linea))`, pongo 
`puts fechar('archivo1')`, sí que lo hace correctamente (aunque solo vale para ese archivo en su directorio, porque lógicamente el resto tienen otro nombre).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es, tal como lo describe el error, que `File.ctime` no encuentra el archivo; para solucionarlo debes considerar tres puntos en tu *script*:

1. Al final de cada línea en el archivo *lista* tienes un caracter para nueva línea (i.e. `\n`) el cual debes eliminar para que el nombre del archivo sea correcto; para verlo puedes utilizar el método `inspect`, por ejemplo:

   ```
   File.readlines('lista').each do |linea|
     puts File.basename(linea).inspect
   end
   ```

   Resultado:

   ```
   archivo1\n
   archivo2\n
   archivo3\n
   archivo4\n
   ```

   Para eliminarlo simplemente debes agregar el método `chomp`:

   ```
   File.readlines('lista').each do |linea|
     puts fechar(File.basename(linea).chomp)
   end
   ```
2. Es importante utilizar el *path* completo de cada archivo para que el *script* lo pueda encontrar. Al utilizar `File.basename(linea).chomp` estás pasando únicamente el nombre del archivo (e.g `archivo1`) como argumento a `File.ctime`, por lo el *script* únicamente funcionaría si se ejecutara desde */home/usuario/prueba/*, y fallaría con las líneas 3 y 4 (debido a los subdirectorios *carpeta1* y *carpeta2*).

   Por lo tanto, es mejor que elimines `File.basename` y pases el nombre del archivo con el *path* completo, así podrás ejecutar tu *script* desde cualquier directorio y siempre encontrarás los archivos, sin importar su ubicación:

   ```
   File.readlines('lista').each do |linea|
     puts fechar(linea.chomp)
   end
   ```
3. Los archivos en *lista* deben tener el *path* **absoluto** para que funcionen, i.e. que al principio tengan `/` (en tu ejemplo la primer línea no funcionaría, las demás están bien).

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona! Efectivamente el problema era el que comentas, el salto de línea. Muchas gracias!!